# How to avoid globals with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In the general explanation of sqlalchemy there is some basic setup where some globals are used. But how to avoid these globals?

 
This is the basic setup:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

databaseName = 'fixedDBName.db'
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + databaseName, echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
class User(declarative_base()):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
            self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)

#Now you can create a session
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
```

Now this rises some questions for me:

Can i just start a database connection when i need it, close it afterwards and start a new one when i need it again?

How do you use it in your projects?

Do you pack everything that has something to do with the database in a class. So that you can create an instance of that function? Like this:

```
class sqlcon():
    def __init__(self, databaseName):
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + databaseName, echo=True)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        
    Base = declarative_base()
        
    class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'users'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)
        fullname = Column(String)
        nickname = Column(String)

        def __repr__(self):
            return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)

    def createTables(self):
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine) #doesn´t work - Base is not Defined
        
    Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine) #doesn´t work - self is not Defined
```

Or
Do you pack this inside a function:

```
def sqlcon(databaseName):
    
   engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + databaseName, echo=True)
       
   Base = declarative_base()
       
   class User(Base):
       __tablename__ = 'users'

       id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
       name = Column(String)
       fullname = Column(String)
       nickname = Column(String)

       def __repr__(self):
           return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
               self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)

   Base.metadata.create_all(engine) 

databaseName = "test_3.db"
alchemy = sqlcon(databaseName)
```

But then how to create a session and how to access the class User?

Here I need a push in the right direction :/

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple: Base just stays a global!

In all the examples on github you find it this way.

im my case it would be:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'users'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)
        fullname = Column(String)
        nickname = Column(String)

        def __repr__(self):
            return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    session = Session(engine)
```